# Time zone issue when using REST Api and JS

Tags: javascript, rest, timezone, handlebars.js, formatjs

I'm using [FormatJS library along with Handlebars](http://formatjs.io/handlebars/) to display a list of events that occured in the past. I'm calling for an endpoint on my server's REST API which returns me the list of events in Json, with datetimes to display for each event. ATM I'm saving datetimes in the DB using GMT time zone.

So when I'm getting my Json, I'm handling datetimes like this :

```
{{formatRelative commentDate}}
```

My issue is, since the datetimes are stocked in GMT, they display also like that. For example, since I'm on a GMT+2 timezone, as soon as a new event is created and shows up on the list, I see it "happened 2 hours ago" while it should be "a few seconds ago".

So, is there a way I can handle this ? Am I making a mistake in saving datetimes in GMT in my DB, and if so, how would you handle datetimes coming from different timezones and displaying them to people in other timezones ?

Of course I could customize the `formatRelative` helper to play with `getTimezoneOffset` and get the wanted result, but I wanted to know if there is something better to do.

Thanks a lot ahead !

Comment: Storing dates in UTC is generally preferred as it makes conversion to any other timezone simple. Also, ECMAScript Date objects are UTC at heart. Your issue seems to be about converting the "JSON" date to local, but you don't show how you're doing that.

Comment: @RobG because I'm not converting anything ! Getting the Json, containing datetimes in the format `2016-02-28 10:15:53` - that's UTC time, using it directly in `formatRelative` helper as shown, not doing anything more.

Comment: Universal time in more central parts of the architecture is a good way to go: http://currentmillis.com/standard/specification/c/ I don't think you are making conceptual mistakes, it sounds like your offset is lost somewhere. http://formatjs.io/handlebars/#formatRelative leads me to believe that what is actually formatted is a time defined as the no of milliseconds since the Epoch, but i see that you are returning a human readable time. Is there a convention that the time returned by the server is interpreted as UTC? (cause you specify no timezone, shouldn't there be a UTC or GMT in the end?)

Comment: @JeremyBelolo—"2016-02-28 10:15:53" is not valid ISO 8601 so parsing is implementation dependent (and may not be parsed at all by some hosts). Consider parsing it yourself (a library can help but a function is 2 lines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to understanding your question is what you wrote in the comments:

> Getting the Json, containing datetimes in the format `2016-02-28 10:15:53` - that's UTC time

You should ensure the value in JSON is in full ISO8601 format, including the appropriate offset or `Z` character to indicate UTC:  `2016-02-28T10:15:53Z`

Without the offset, most implementations will consider the value to be represented in *local time*, which explains your results.

Thus, the problem is with your server-side code, not your JavaScript code.  There may be a client-side workaround you could apply when the date string is parsed from JSON, but really the best solution would be to qualify it at the server.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will try it and validate the answer whenever I see it working

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks :) I just wonder why MySQL is not storing datetimes directly on this format, rather than the one I wrote ?

Comment: Databases (most of them anyway) don't store datetimes as strings at all.  They're stored in a custom binary format that is usually based on number of x units since y date.  They might be formatted as strings as you view them in a utility, or use them in your own software.  Many db's don't even send strings over the wire in their native protocols.  It's not until you are *consuming* them that a format applies.  The same is true for numbers.  Consider `1,234.567`.  The DB doesn't store the comma or the decimal point.